# How to use cocoapods dependency in Flutter package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I want to use cocoapods [Printer](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Printer) Plugin with my Flutter packages.  how can i add this to packages ?

Comment: Use platformchannels: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: @Rene it about platform specific code, i need to add platform external dependency using cocoapods